# I am trying to make a banner slideshow in html in which each image slide is a different link you can click on, but the links aren't working properly

Tags: html

The way the slideshow banner should work is that it should automatically slide through depending on a pre determined timer. Each image / slide is a unique link which is accessed by clicking the image.

Another feature is that the banner shows up different on mobile and desktop. On desktop, the 3 images in the slideshow are completely different to the 3 images shown up on mobile. This is so that the viewing experience is better depending on the device. However 1st, 2nd, and 3rd slide on both devices lead to the same place.

I have written the code and I will post it below. Everything works perfectly, except the links. The links always lead to the 3rd slides link no matter what slide it is on. If it is on the first slide it leads to the 3rd link and if it is on the 2nd slide it leads to the third link. The same problem persists on mobile.

I tried changing to jQuery but nothing worked

```js
// JavaScript code for the slideshow
var desktopSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.desktop-slide');
var mobileSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-slide');
var currentDesktopSlide = 0;
var currentMobileSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 4500); // Change slide every 3.5 seconds
var interactionTimeout;
var isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 480; // Check if the device is mobile

function nextSlide() {
  resetInteractionTimeout();
  if (isMobile) {
    mobileSlides[currentMobileSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentMobileSlide = (currentMobileSlide + 1) % mobileSlides.length;
    mobileSlides[currentMobileSlide].className = 'slide active';
  } else {
    desktopSlides[currentDesktopSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentDesktopSlide = (currentDesktopSlide + 1) % desktopSlides.length;
    desktopSlides[currentDesktopSlide].className = 'slide active';
  }
}

function previousSlide() {
  resetInteractionTimeout();
  if (isMobile) {
    mobileSlides[currentMobileSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentMobileSlide = (currentMobileSlide - 1 + mobileSlides.length) % mobileSlides.length;
    mobileSlides[currentMobileSlide].className = 'slide active';
  } else {
    desktopSlides[currentDesktopSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentDesktopSlide = (currentDesktopSlide - 1 + desktopSlides.length) % desktopSlides.length;
    desktopSlides[currentDesktopSlide].className = 'slide active';
  }
}

function resetInteractionTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(interactionTimeout);
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
  slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 4500);
  interactionTimeout = setTimeout(startInteraction, 10000); // Reset timeout if there's user interaction
}

function startInteraction() {
  clearTimeout(interactionTimeout);
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
  slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 4500);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 480;
  startInteraction();
});

document.getElementById('nextBtn').addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
document.getElementById('prevBtn').addEventListener('click', previousSlide);
```

```css
/* CSS Styles for the slideshow */

.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
  /* Added object-position property */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.slideshow .slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slideshow .slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* CSS Styles for mobile slideshow */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop-slide {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-slide {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .mobile-slide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <a href="https://example.com/1"><img class="slide active desktop-slide" src="https://picture.com/1" alt="Slide 1"></a>
  <a href="https://example.com/2"><img class="slide desktop-slide" src="https://picture.com/2" alt="Slide 2"></a>
  <a href="https://example.com/3"><img class="slide desktop-slide" src="https://picture.com/3" alt="Slide 3"></a>
  <a href="https://example.com/mobile1"><img class="slide active mobile-slide" src="https://picture.com/1" alt="Mobile Slide 1"></a>
  <a href="https://example.com/mobile2"><img class="slide mobile-slide" src="https://picture.com/mobile2" alt="Mobile Slide 2"></a>
  <a href="https://example.com/mobile3"><img class="slide mobile-slide" src="https://picture.com/mobile3" alt="Mobile Slide 3"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You have a console error due to missing buttons

Comment: You have `https://picture.com/1` instead of `https://picture.com/mobile1` and where do you read that the user wanted to load that image? Where is the code from the picture site?

Comment: I tried running your snippet but the same problem persists. All the links lead to the https://example.com/3 when they should lead to whatever the slide is on (https://example.com/1 or https://example.com/2)

Comment: I did NOT change your code, just made it into a snippet!!!
There is NOTHING in your script that changes the links. It is the site you go to that changes what they show when you go there

Comment: I still have not found a solution. Can someone explain why, even though I put a href tag with the images, they don't individually work?

Comment: Not from the code you posted. I don't think it is related to the code but to the target server